# Comparing Values of an array using if statement

Tags: powershell

I'm Having trouble checking to see if my $Grades array falls in the range of the $Values array and how can I fix this problem?

```
$Global:Values = 1..100
#$Global:Grades[0] = 5000 $Global:Grades[1] = 30

if($Global:Grades[0] -gt $Global:Values[0] -and $Global:Grades[0] -lt $Global:Values[99])
{
    Write-Host "Works!"
}
```

Comment: What do you want to find out? That all grades are in range? That at least one grade is in range?

Comment: I wanted just to find out if all $Grades are in range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Where-Object` cmdlet (alias `where`) to filter an array:

```
$Values = 1..100
$Grades = 5000,30
$GradesNotInRange = $Grades | where { $Values -notcontains $_ }

if ($GradesNotInRange) {
    "These grades are not valid: $GradesNotInRange"
} else {
    "All grades are valid."
}
```

Produces this output for me:

```
These grades are not valid: 5000
```

Notes

- Don't use the `Global` scope. When it's time to use it, you will know. As long as you are not 100% sure, don't use it. (Personally I have never come across a situation where using it was necessary. I doubt you will.)
- You can create an array with a simple comma-delimited list of values.
- The `-contains` operator checks for exact matches in an array. `-notcontains` does the opposite.
- When no values match the `where` condition, `$GradesNotInRange` will be `$null`, and null is treated like false in the `if` check.

Comment: I don't understand when it comes to using arrays in Powershell is there a guide you can give me?

Comment: I guess you will find tons of tutorials, blog posts, and documentation if you just look for them.